# magento 2 | customer account is disabled temporarily

Tags: magento, magento2

on of my customers complained that he cant login from mobile app even if he reset the password, when he try to login from web it works but mobile app dose not work, as we know the mobile app is connected to magento through magento API so i tired to test the customer account using postman and it has the same error

```
"The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later."
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason why this is happening because the total failure attempts to login has reached the maximum over the account life time, magento keeps count of all failure attempts in a table called "oauth_token_request_log"

the solution to this is to empty the table or just remove the record that has the user record, below is the SQL command to run to delete all records in the table

```
DELETE FROM oauth_token_request_log;
```

you may also want to create a cronjob to run this sql command every day for example to make sure it wont happen again